# Different versions of python-requests on identical systems

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-requests

I have two VMs, both running Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

```
 $ cat /etc/issue
 Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS \n \l
```

And I have installed python-requests through apt-get on both systems. However, on one VM I have version 1.2.3 and the other 0.8.2..

```
>>> requests.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.pyc'
>>> requests.__version__
'1.2.3'
```

The other system:

```
>>> requests.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.pyc'
>>> requests.__version__
'0.8.2'
```

How can this be? What might I have done that caused this?

I can see that the **file** indicates that the newer version is located in /usr/local, can that give any hint of the problem?

Comment: Did you install them both with the same user/at the same sudo level?  Maybe that could make a difference...  Could also be a difference in pythonpath/path configuration, causing the import to give priority to different directories between the 2 VMs, combined with having 2 installs of requests.

Comment: @SilasRay yes, same user, but with pip was used to install it as well as apt-get, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by having installed python-requests by

```
$ pip install requests
```

on the VM with the newer version. That places it in /usr/local, and that directory is a prioritized Python path.